# Rendering an array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im new to react so im not sure whats going wrong here...
Im trying to create a 3x3 structure of input boxes. This is what i came up with

```
function Square(prop){
    return (<input type = 'text' class='w-25'  style="display:inline-block">${prop.key}</input>);
}

function Row(props){
    const row =[];
    for( let i=props.key*3;i<(props.key+3);i++){
        row.push(<Square key ={i}/>);
    }
    return (row);
}

class Box extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
            xIsNext: true,
        };
    }
    render(){
        let board =[];
        for( let i=0; i<3;i++){
            board.push(<div><Row key={i} /></div>);
        } 
        return (board);
    }
} 
ReactDOM.render(
    <Box />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

But I am getting the error

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

As far as my Dom goes the 3 rows have been rendered as

> Any help would be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**

After trying out some answers given below I've ended up with a single row of 4 input boxes... although I've only specified 3 in the loop. Why is this can some one explain and I've specified 2 more rows.This is the new code

```
function Square(prop){
    return (<input type = 'text' id={prop.value} value={'x'}></input>);
}

function Row(props){
    const row =[];
    for( let i=props.value*3;i<(props.value+3);i++){
        const val = `${i}input`;
        const key = `${i}square`;
        row.push(<Square key ={key} value={val}/>);

    }
    return (row);
}

class Box extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
            xIsNext: true,
        };
    }
    render(){
        let board =[];
        for( let i=0; i<3;i++){
            const key = `${i}row`;
            board.push( <Row  key={key} value={i}/>);
            console.log(i)
        } 
        return (board);
    }
} 
ReactDOM.render(
    <Box />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: `for( let i=props.key*3;i<(props.key+3);i++)` Are you sure this is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key prop should be on the first element of the iteration which is the `div` element:

```
board.push(<div key={i}><Row /></div>);
```

Also note that this row `for( let i=props.key*3;i<(props.key+3);i++)` might not work for you as there is not more key prop.

You can change it to: `for( let i=0;i<3;i++)`

Notice that it is an **Anti-Pattern** to use index as a key.

> a key is the only thing React uses to identify DOM elements. What
>   happens if you push an item to the list or remove something in the
>   middle? If the key is same as before React assumes that the DOM
>   element represents the same component as before. But that is no longer
>   true.

Took from [This medium - Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

**EDIT:**

Added a sample code that should run for you.

Notice I've removed the Row component as it seem redundant.

I didn't understood why you need two for loops? Do you need 9 inputs or 3 inputs?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function Square(props) {
  return (<input type='text' id={props.key} value={props.value}></input>);
}

class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
    };
  }
  render() {
    let board = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      const key = `${i}row`;
      board.push(<Square key={key} value={i} />);
      console.log(i)
    }
    return (board);
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Box />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thanks but now im getting a single row of 4 input boxes. Note why am i getting 4 when ive specified only 3 in the loop.also a single row ???

Comment: Apparently I have 3 input-boxes from first row and 1 input- box from second row

Comment: @AkshayKishore , I've added an Edit section to my answer.

Comment: @AkshayKishore , It's ok, No worries. Good luck friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to move [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) property:

```
board.push(<div key={i}><Row /></div>);
```

Because `key` should be in the outside element of each element in array

Answer (score 0):

You should **use key in parent element** ie. `div` in your example:

```
for( let i=0; i<3;i++){
  board.push(<div key={i}><Row /></div>);
}
```

BTW, you may simply use:

```
for( let i=0; i<3;i++){
  board.push(<Row key={i} />);
}
```

Best practice is to use some string rather than assigning number value so it will not conflict with other key of element:

```
for( let i=0; i<3;i++){
  board.push(<Row key={'row-'+i} />);
}
```